# Differences between C# async and Java ExecutorService

Tags: c#, java, future, async-await

C# has a cool new feature

```
public Task<string> async f()
{
    string r = LongCompute();
    return r;
}
```

but isn't that equivalent to

```
public Future<String> f() {
    return Globals.executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String r = longCompute();
            return r;
        }
    });
}
```

where in Java you have more flexibility to choose the threadpool in which the task would run.

What about await? It's equivalent to just calling get

```
string s = await f();
```

is just like

```
String s = f().get();
```

Is there anything more to C#, or is it indeed just a syntactic sugar to the Java version? (I'm not a C# guru, so I might be missing something).

Comment: Did you mean `string r = await LongCompute();`? If not, then your method will not be asynchronous at all (and the compiler will tell you that in the form of a warning).

Comment: @svick the method body won't, but the caller of the method will.

Comment: Nope, it won't. If you call `await f()`, it will be rewritten exactly as Jon explained in his answer, but it will still run completely synchronously. That's because running things asynchronously incurs some overhead, and the framework tries to avoid it if possible. So, for example, any code in an `async` method before the first `await` runs synchronously.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, `await` is *not* like just calling `get()`. There's *considerably* more to it.

When you use an `await` expression in C#, the compiler effectively creates a continuation, so that if the awaitable hasn't completed yet, the method can immediately return, and continue processing only when it's completed. The continuation will run in an appropriate context - so if you're on a UI thread before the `await` expression, you'll continue on the UI thread afterwards, but without blocking the UI thread while you're waiting for the result. For example:

```
public async void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // All of this method will run in the UI thread, which it needs
    // to as it touches the UI... however, it won't block when it does
    // the web operation.

    string url = urlTextBox.Text;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string webText = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

    // Continuation... automatically called in the UI thread, with appropriate
    // context (local variables etc) which we used earlier.
    sizeTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0}: {1}", url, webText.Length); 
}
```

Ultimately it's all syntactic sugar, but *much* more complicated sugar than what you've shown.

There's a lot of detailed information available on the web already. For example:

- [Eric Lippert's blog](https://ericlippert.com/category/asynchrony/)
- The [Microsoft C# async/await guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
- [My own blog posts about async](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/async/)

Comment: But if you don't care which thread runs what, isn't it effectively equivalent. Continuation on line 12, is equivalent to having a thread blocking on line 12, isn't it? The only gain is to have everything running on the same thread, which is usually useful only because the UI thread is privileged. Am I correct?

Comment: @Chi-Lan: Not really. Suppose you have a server which is meant to implement long polling, so may have hundreds of thousands of active connections. At that point you *really* don't want the thread-per-request model, so you can't block waiting for "whatever's going to trigger a response". So you need to have *some* sort of continuation mechanism - and the language support in C# 5 makes that really simple; it lets you write code which looks and feels like the synchronous code we're relatively good at writing, but with asynchronous properties.

Comment: hmmm... got you. It's equivalent to the lightweight/green threads model we see popping around lately, eg golang.org with the ability to mark which real thread do you want to run your coroutine. Am I correct now, eventually?

Comment: @Chi-Lan: Possibly - but I'd have to know more about those to be able to comment, to be honest. You would be better off following the links I included to find out what it *actually* entails.

Comment: I did before following the question, but those explain how to use it, not why are they different than "regular" futures. You have referred me to links with many articles of variety level about all sorts of async related material (VS first example for instance, doesn't really care about await not using a different thread). I could just as well google it. If you have something more precise, that explains the essence of it (maybe its implementation) it would be more helpful for me. Comparison to topics I know will also help.Similar googling lead me to the wrong conclusion in the question.

Comment: @Chi-Lan: The C# language specification (linked from the right hand side of the Visual Studio async home page) is pretty precise in terms of the language features. If you read my Eduasync blog series it builds it up from scratch, too. (Admittedly the feature has evolved over time, but it's fundamentally the same.) I'd rather steer clear of comparisons which may well not be entirely accurate. I've provided you specific links to material I trust - which is the difference between "just searching" and following the links I've given.

Comment: +1 for maintaining composure and providing great information as usual. Funny to see someone "arguing" with Jon Skeet (or anyone with over 550k reputation).

Answer (score 12):

Jon didn't explain the *real point*.

Java's `ExecutorService` is based on *threads*, while C#'s `await` can be said to be based on *fibers*.

Both allow multitasking, which splits computing resources between concurrent functions (ie, functions that run "simultaneously"). The first kind of multitasking is called *pre-emptive*, while the second *co-operative*. Historically, preemptive multitasking was considered more advanced and superior to cooperative. Indeed, before preemptive multitasking became supported by consumer operating systems, computers really sucked. However, preemptive multitasking has its shortcomings. It can be hard to program for, and it uses more memory.

The main difference between the two is that preemptive multitasking allows the runtime (usually, the operating system itself) to stop any function at any time and start a different function (and to run them simultaneously on different CPUs). Meanwhile, cooperative multitasking requires the running function to end or to voluntarily pause. Most of us are familiar with preemptive multitasking in the form of multithreading, as well as the kind of careful programming that goes with it. Fewer are familiar with cooperative multitasking, which nowdays is often called fibers or coroutines (in which case it's implemented in userland inside the threads of a preemptive OS).

Anyway, the point is that `ExecutorService` and `await` are not directly comparable, and `await` isn't, in general, superior to real multithreading (except that it features nice syntactic sugar). C#'s reason for including `await` (and basing it on cooperative multitasking) is that the major GUI toolkits on the platform are not designed for multithreading and refactoring them to support concurrency would take a boatload of work. Cooperative multitasking works well for the UI because most of the event handlers are short and can be executed serially. `await` extends the concept of the event loop by letting long event handlers pause themselves and resume after the rendering function gets a chance to run. All of this happens in a single thread on a single CPU core.

Where they both find common ground is that they're both forms of multitasking, and `Future.get` and `await Task` are both forms of synchronization.

As can be expected, C# is not without good support for threads and thread pools. Likewise, Java contains fibers/co-routines/async in many libraries, such as Servlet 3.0 and `javafx.concurrent.Task`.

In response to Jon Skeet: *Continuation* (as the userland implementation mechanism of fibers is called) is non-trivial, but threads are no less sophisticated in their implementation. Jon may have been thrown off because the algorithms behind threads are in the OS rather than in the compiler or .NET runtime.

Comment: Thank you for this - 20yrs of Java & 3-4yrs of C# and I could not find as insightful an analysis of what's going on "under the hood".

Answer (score 5):

Just to extend correct Jon Skeet's answer.

The is no Java analog of C# await expressions. Hoverer, some Java frameworks have same functionality:

- Servlet 3.0
- javafx.concurrent.Task
- Kilim: https://github.com/kilim/kilim
- Apache JavaFlow: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-javaflow/

In fact, they generate routines or state-machine code on-fly.

Comment: Kilim does not generate state machines, it uses lightweight routines.